# Looking to pay for consultation on circuit-project. Here?

Tags: support

If I was looking to pay for free-lance consultation on circuit-project, where on this site would I start?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Our [EE.SE chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/15/electrical-engineering) is the only place on EE.SE to ask about paid freelance consultations.